# Regex shorthand for matching special characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm building a password validator for the back-end of a web app and I'm using the pretty standard uppercase, lowercase, digit, min length and special character requirement, and I'm looking to refactor a bit the regex so it's more compact. Is there a way to search for a match of any special character without having a pretty long regex with every special character written?

```
r'^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[special chars regex])[\w\d special chars regex]{8,255}$'
```

So far my attempts have been around the idea of having a negation set like \S, which works to match them but since they also match digits, then it's still allowing for passwords with no special characters.

EDIT:
What I mean with special characters can be summarized as, I want to catch characters with ASCII index between 33 and 126, excluding letters and digits (indexes 48 ~ 57 for digits, 65 ~ 90 for upper case letters and 97 ~ 122 for lower case letters) as those are indeed part of pre-existing regex short hands such as `\w` and `\d`.

Here's an [ASCII chart](https://asciichart.com/) for reference.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by special characters?

Comment: Good catch there, I will edit the question now to define it better

Answer (score 0):

`[^\w\s\d]` will match a single character that's not a word character (lowercase or uppercase), a number, or a whitespace character.

That would mean you would in theory use `[\w\d[^\w\d\s]]` to indicate all the characters that a password can be composed of, but since that union doesn't seem to want to parse correctly, you can specify the Unicode range explicitly (though in hex, not decimal):

```
(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^\w\d\s])[\u0021-\u007E]{8,255}
```